# Do action to every row in SQL

Tags: mysql

I have one table that essentially looks like:

```
chandty 244 4/10/2015   32  2   3
chandty 245 4/12/2015   32  9   10
couside 247 10/29/2014  24  4   14
couside 248 10/31/2014  24  6   16
```

I am trying to preform an action on every row with the name chandty then, every row with couside, down the list. I created a table with all the distinct values of that column in it and am now attempting to use that to loop through the table but cant seem to get the syntax right. What am I doing wrong? I was originally trying this in phpMyAdmin. Here is the code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE leagueavgs()
BEGIN
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `playername`)
BEGIN
    SET @tempname = (SELECT `PlayerNames`
                       FROM `playername`
                       ORDER BY `PlayerNames` ASC
                       LIMIT 1)

    INSERT INTO `2015 average stats` (`Player Name`, `PTS`, `3PT`, `FG%`, `FT%`,`FTA`, `REB`, `AST`, `STL`, `BLK`, `TOV`)
    SELECT  `Player Name`, AVG(`PTS`), AVG(`3PT`), AVG(`FGM`)/AVG(FGA), AVG(FTM)/AVG(`FTA`), AVG(`FTA`), AVG(`REB`), AVG(`AST`), AVG(`STL`), AVG(`BLK`), AVG(`TOV`)
    FROM `2015 gamelogs`  WHERE `Player Name` = @tempname

    DELETE `playername`
    WHERE PlayerNames = @tempname
```

Comment: First thing that comes to mind are session variables (defined by @) should not be DECLAREd, just SET and used.

Comment: I still get a syntax error at that set line

Comment: What are you using for statement delimiters?

Comment: There is no need for a stored procedure here. Take your `INSERT` statement, remove the `WHERE` clause, append `GROUP BY \`Player Name\``

Comment: Ah that's perfect thank you!